# What are those functional functions called?

Tags: function, haskell, clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I'm looking for a functional way to implement this:

```
list = [a b c d e f]
foo(list, 3) = [[a d] [b e] [c f]]
```

A potential solution is:

```
foo(list,spacing) = zip(goo(list,spacing))
```

Where, for example,

```
goo([a b c d e f],3) = [[a b c] [d e f]]
```

What is `foo` and `goo` usually called, so I can look for existing solutions rather than reinventing the wheel?

*Notes: Rather than trying to explain with words, I've just shown examples that'll be hopefully much easier to get. Arbitrary syntax for broader understanding.*

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is "higher order function" or "combinator".

Comment: Are `c` and `d` switched in your first example? What should happen if the input list is more than twice as long as the input number?

Comment: @DanielWagner it was very wrong, sorry. `foo` is the equivalent of `zip(partition(list,spacing))`, as mobyte pointed, but maybe it doesn't have a name.

Comment: I don't think these are higher order functions, since they don't take a function as argument(s).

Comment: Hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) lets you search the Haskell standard library by *type*, not just name. So if it seems like a function you want should be "obvious" but you're not sure what it would be called, and you can figure out the Haskell type it would have, you can try Hoogle. It's not always perfect, but it can often be helpful. Even if you're wanting to find the function in a different language, it might at least give you a common name by which it is known.

Comment: Terms to google: "sliding window" or "moving window": take n at a time; "zip" corresponding items of 2 lists/streams together; "transpose" across axes of array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [partition](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partition):

```lisp
(partition 3 '[a b c d e f])
=> ((a b c) (d e f))

(partition 2 '[a b c d e f])
=> ((a b) (c d) (e f))
```

**Edit:**

```lisp
(apply map list (partition 3 '[a b c d e f]))
=> ((a d) (b e) (c f))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. What about "foo" itself, does it have a name?

Comment: This is an implementation, not the name, lol! I appreciate the good intention though, have a tick.

Comment: A partition function is one that takes a predicate p and splits a list into the elements for which p holds and the one for which it doesn't. So it's not the appropriate name for goo. I am not aware of a common name for it, but you might call it break or divide.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a built-in function for that. It's easy and nice to implement.

I know you do not want the implementation, but one of the tags was Haskell so maybe you want to see this

```
 p :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
 p n xs = [  [x | (x ,y) <- ys , y `mod` n == i]  |  i <- [0 .. n - 1] ,  let ys = zip xs [0 .. ]]
```

That is pretty functional.

Answer (score 1):

Your `goo` function is `drop` with flipped arguments. Given that, you can implement `foo` almost like you say in your question:

```
let foo list spacing = zip list (drop spacing list)
```

This still doesn't exactly give the result you need though, but close:

```
Prelude> foo "abcdef" 3
[('a','d'),('b','e'),('c','f')]
```

---

EDIT:

Reading more carefully, your `goo` function is `splitAt` with flipped arguments. Given that, `foo` can be defined like this:

```
let foo list spacing = (uncurry zip) $ splitAt spacing list
```

Which is the same as:

```
let foo list spacing = let (left, right) = splitAt spacing list
                       in zip left right
```

Comment: Nice! How did you find it?

Comment: I think I've read about it in the LYAH book. It covers most of those anyway :)